# Reading in values into Array

Tags: c#

This program asks the user for an array size then asks the user to enter in the array values. The problem I am having is that the for loop to read in the array values doesn't work properly. No matter what is the value for `n`it will sitll ask for a lot more inputs.

```
int n;

Console.WriteLine("Enter how many values you are entering in");
n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

int[] arr = new int[n];
Console.WriteLine("Enter your values in");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
}
```

Comment: Use `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.Read()`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek you should run the code before speculating ...

Comment: @Bogdan What makes you think I didn't?

Comment: @Bogdan except that readline is probably what the OP actually wants...

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek because your suggestion does not fix the issue.

Comment: by itself, no, it doesn't fix the issue.  but it is headed in the right direction...

Comment: @FJam: Set a break point on the line "arr[i] = ...", then hit F5 to run. Now check the value of n. Did you notice how much it is?

Comment: It fixes the issue. `Convert.ToInt32(string input)` uses `int.Parse` under the hoods.

Comment: @JohnGardner Lol, not even close - Read() works just fine, the issue is that the OP is not parsing the input correctly.

Comment: @Bogdan You're wrong. `Console.Read` returns `int` which represents numeric value of next character from input. So if you type `10` into console and call `Console.Read()` twice you'll get `50` and `49`. That's where the problem is. Try it!

Comment: Read doesn't work if you wanted to enter 10 numbers

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yeah, seems like I was wrong :) Sorry for the trouble ...

Comment: I have solved it and proved it...  ReadKey() is what he needs to do. My answer has it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick and easy fix:**

Use `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` in place of your `Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read())`

**Explanation:**

You were getting the ASCII value the way you were doing it. For example, if you would type in the number `2` your `n` variable would have actually been set to `50`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Um I said ReadLine?

Answer (score 0):

Use ReadLine() to get the number, then use ReadKey() not Read() or ReadLine() when entering the chararcters

```
int n;

Console.WriteLine("Enter how many values you are entering in");
n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int[] arr = new int[n];
Console.WriteLine("Enter your values in");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  char c = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
  arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.Read()`.

As documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx), Console.Read() returns only a single character.  You probably want to read in the entire line and parse it for the integer value.

This code should do what you want:

```
int n;

Console.WriteLine("Enter how many values you are entering in");
//n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int[] arr = new int[n];
Console.WriteLine("Enter your values in");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

This works in the input case of n = 10 as well.

Answer (score 0):

here is a version with some more robust error checking.
Note: (entering this directly without running, so I apologise if there are minor syntax errors)

```
        int count;

        bool attemptedSetCount = false;
        do
        {
            if (attemptedSetCount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter how many values you are entering in");
            string countString = Console.ReadLine();
            attemptedSetCount = true;
        }
        while (!Int32.TryParse(countString, out count));

        int[] arr = new int[n];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your values in");

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            string valString = (Console.ReadLine());
            int val;
            if(!Int32.TryParse(valString, out val))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer");
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[i] = val;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     string value = Console.ReadLine();
     int result;
     if (int.TryParse(value, out result)) arr[i] = result;
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid value try again.");
         i--;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Console.Read` function reads the next single character of input and returns it as as `int` value.  The code then passes it to the `Convert.ToInt32` API which will essentially return the exact value that was passed in.  This means that numbers like `1` which have the character value `49` will be processed as `49`.  This is why your code is reading in so many values

To properly read a number from the `Console` use the `ReadLine` method which returns a `String`.  This can then be passed to `Int32.Parse` and converted to an `int`

```
Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Or better yet, just abstract this out to a method

```
static int ReadInt() {
  return Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Have you read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

> The `Read` method blocks its return while you type input characters;
>   it terminates when you press the Enter key. Pressing Enter appends a
>   platform-dependent line termination sequence to your input (for example,
>   Windows appends a carriage return-linefeed sequence). **Subsequent calls to the
>   Read method retrieve your input one character at a time.** After the final
>   character is retrieved, Read blocks its return again and the cycle repeats.
>
> Note that you will not get a property value of -1 unless you perform one of the
>   following actions: simultaneously press the Control modifier key and Z console
>   key (Ctrl+Z), which signals the end-of-file condition; press an equivalent key
>   that signals the end-of-file condition, such as the F6 function key in Windows;
>   or redirect the input stream to a source, such as a text file, that has an actual
>   end-of-file character.
>
> The `ReadLine` method, or the `KeyAvailable` property and `ReadKey` method are
>   preferable to using the Read method.

If I execute this code:

```
Console.Write("? ") ;
int input = Console.Read() ;
Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}.", input ) ;
Console.WriteLine( "{0} is the decimal code point for the character whose glyph is '{1}.'" , input , (char)input ) ;
```

And, if I, at the `?` prompt, enter the characters `123` followed by the `return` key:

```
? 123<return>
```

I'll see this output:

```
You entered 49.
49 is the decimal code point for the character whose glyph is '1'.
```

[**Note that** in Windows, you can generate a '1' at the command prompt by holding down the `<ALT>` key, typing '0049`and releasing the`` key.]

Assuming that the intent is for the user to specify a number of values to be entered and to then prompt them for that many input values, you want code that looks something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
  int   n      = ReadIntegerFromConsole( "How many values do you want to enter?" ) ;
  int[] values = new int[n] ;

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < values.Length ; ++i )
  {
    string prompt = string.Format( "{0}/{1}?" , i , n ) ;

    values[i] = ReadIntegerFromConsole(prompt) ;

  }

  Console.WriteLine( "You entered: {0}" , string.Join(", ",values) ) ;
  return ;
}

static int ReadIntegerFromConsole( string prompt )
{
  int  value   ;
  bool isValid ;

  do
  {

    Console.Write( prompt) ;
    Console.Write( ' ' );

    string text = Console.ReadLine() ;

    isValid = int.TryParse(text, out value ) ;

    prompt = "That's not an integer. Try again:" ;
  } while (!isValid) ;

  return value ;
}
```